# On what stages can I farm Lesser (**) Black Orbs?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

Other than the appropriate weekly event, on Tuesdays, which stages offer the best drop rate for Lesser Black Orbs?

Comment: The second boss on Baron Castle (ff4) seems to be reliably dropping these for me but its a lot of stamina to spend for just one so very likely not best return.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have obtained lesser black orbs from Mt. Kolts (VI), Abandoned Mineshaft (VI) and Imperial Camp (VI). I had the most success on Mt. Kolts, but I'm not sure if that was coincidence or if the enemy that drops them in this level appears more often.